# Stripe ID saves to a new row in Django AbstractUser table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stripe-payments

I was able to successfully complete a test subscription payment through Stripe. However, when I checked my Postgresql user database table, I found that during the checkout and Stripe customer creation process, the StripeID and Stripe_subscription_id were saved to a new user. The desired behavior is for these two pieces of data to be added to the current logged-in user's profile. I am using a custom AbstractUser model and suspect the issue lies there. I appreciate a point in the right direction to fixing this.

[image]

My relevant code snippets are below:

### models.py

```
# users/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    # add additional fields in here
    stripeid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

### forms.py

```
# users/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

### views.py

```
# pages/views.py
import os
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from users.models import CustomUser
import stripe

stripe.api_key = os.environ.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')

def checkout(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        stripe_customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=request.user.email, source=request.POST['stripeToken'])
        plan = 'redacted' # MONTHLY plan ID from Stripe subscriptions
        if request.POST['plan'] == 'yearly':
            plan = 'redacted' # YEARLY plan ID from Stripe subscriptions
        else:
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(customer=stripe_customer.id,
            items=[{'plan':plan}])

        customer = CustomUser()
        customer.user = request.user
        customer.stripeid = stripe_customer.id
        customer.membership = True
        customer.cancel_at_period_end = False
        customer.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id
        customer.save()

        return redirect('home')    
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: But that's not right. CustomUser doesn't *have* a `user` attribute, it *is* a user. You should do `customer = request.user`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I just tried that and it solved the problem. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.